# Azure Graph API does not return newly updated data

Tags: caching, azure-ad-graph-api

Precondition:

1. Admin of Azure AD goes to azure portal to change/update user data
   such as First Name from **Test 1** to **Test 2**.
2. Call graph api: https://graph.windows.net/tenant/users?api-version=1.6 immediately.
3. Do nothing and wait for about 20-30s then call above graph api again.

Actual:

- On step 2, the api returns user's First Name : *Test 1*
- On step 3, the api returns user's First Name : *Test 2*

My question is why azure does not return newly updated data on step 2 and how to bypass and immediately get the newly data after updating from azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD is a large behemoth of a system. There are multiple data centers around the world, each with copies of the data; and in order to ensure that we give you the absolute best performance we may route different calls through different sources to different data centers.

My guess is that because you are using one tool to do the update, and another tool to do the read, you are seeing propagation delay between the actual source of authority for those two systems at the time of the call.

If you made the update and read call with using the same service, I believe you would not see this problem.

Comment: I have only 1 service which is a Web API app. It will read the users from Azure, if there is any changes from Azure, it will apply to user's data in my database.
I made changes to user's data using https://manage.windowsazure.com.

Comment: Right... but manage.windowsazure.com is a different service from your web api. You should expect replication delay.

Comment: ok. How can I check that the replication is running so that that app won't need to get old data?